# Rspec Arrays not working as they should be?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

The test should update the item (which is already created) with the tag_id that was placed into the tag_id parameter. I know that I can do this because I have tried it on postman and it works every time. Rspec tells me that the tags is invalid even though I logged its id (which means that it exists).

Any help would be appreciated.

[rspec code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwm9P.png)
[error message with logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAyiD.png)

I tried to change the way of input; I've placed "tag.id" into the array expecting it to read it as an integer and I have tried every other way of inputting the number into the array.

I also know that the problem is with the array because once I leave it empty (aka: []) it works perfectly fine.

Note: I am 100% sure that the code works because it works on postman.

Code in items_controller.rb for updating an item:

```
def update

    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.item_tags.destroy_all
    error_exist = false

    params[:tag_id].each do |tag_id|
      if ItemTag.find_by(tag_id: tag_id) == nil
        error_exist = true
        break
      else
        item.tags << Tag.find(tag_id)
      end
    end
    @items = item

    if error_exist == false
      if current_user.id == item.user_id
        if item.update(item_params)
          if item.is_sold == true
            if item.bids.last != nil
              item.bids.last.update_attribute(:is_accepted, true)
            end
          else
            if item.bids.last != nil
              item.bids.last.update_attribute(:is_accepted, false)
            end
          end
          render 'items/update'
        else
          render json: {status: "Error", message: "Item not updated", data:item.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      else
        render json: {status: "Error", message: "Item is not yours"}, status: :unauthorized
      end
    else
      render json: {status: "Error", message: "Invalid tags"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private

  def item_params
    params.permit(:name, :price, :is_auction, :is_sold)
  end
```

Note 2: Passing in nothing, a single tag_id, or multiple tags should work. The only time it would render invalid tags is if one of the tag_is does not exist.

Comment: Screenshots make it hard to answer your question. Would you paste your code into the question, please?

Comment: what is your code please

Comment: The invalid tag message is not coming from rspec, it is coming from the controller you're testing. We'd need to see the relevant part of the controller to help.

Comment: Are you sure the singular tag_id parameter takes an array?

Comment: I have updated my post. I am also sure that "tag_id" takes in multiple parameters because I have tried it on postman and it works. The only thing I can think about is if postman does something behind the scenes to accept the array, but I have not idea since I am new to this stuff.

Comment: Once again, code and text in images makes it harder to understand and answer your question. Please provide the text in your images as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
    params[:tag_id].each do |tag_id|
      if ItemTag.find_by(tag_id: tag_id) == nil
        error_exist = true
        break
      else
        item.tags << Tag.find(tag_id)
      end
    end
```

Your test passes `Tag.last.id` as `tag_id` but your code is searching by `ItemTag.find_by(tag_id: tag_id)`. The conclusion is that the tag is missing from `ItemTag`.

---

Digging deeper, you're not asking "does this tag exist", but "does *any* item already use this tag" which seems odd.

You're also deleting all the tags from the item in question, which will impact the tag not being in ItemTag...

```
    item = Item.find(params[:id])
    item.item_tags.destroy_all
```

...and then pushing the new tags on one by one. I think the intent is to make sure you fully replace the item's tags, but this is done with `item.tags = tags`.

---

A better approach is to replace the tags in one go.

```
# Check if the item exists.
item = Item.find(params[:id])
if !item
  # Not found is the appropriate response. See
  # https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/
  render json: {status: "Error", message: "Item #{params[:id]} was not found"}, status: :not_found
  return
end

# Get the tags, make sure they exist.
begin
  tags = Tag.find(params[:tag_Id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  # Not found is the appropriate response. See
  # https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/
  render json: {status: "Error", message: "Tag #{e.primary_key} was not found"}, status: :not_found
  return
end

# Delete and add tags as necessary.
item.tags = tags
```